# Sticky element doesn't hide and show as expected

Tags: jquery, sticky

Ok so I have:

```
<div class="testplace"></div>

<div class="footer_navigation"><div class="checkout-btn"></div></div>

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var elem2Query = ".footer_navigation .checkout-btn";
    var elem2Hide = ".testplace";
    var jElem2Hide = $(elem2Hide);
    if (isElementInView()) jElem2Hide.addClass("hideClass");    
    $(window).scroll(function(){ 
        if (isElementInView()){
            jElem2Hide.fadeOut(0);
        }else{
            jElem2Hide.fadeIn(0);
        }
    });
    function isElementInView(){     
        var jWindow = $(window);
        var jElem   = $(elem2Query);
        var pageViewTop = jWindow.scrollTop();
        var pageViewBottom = pageViewTop + jWindow.height();
        var elemTop = jElem.offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + jElem.height();
        var isInView =((elemBottom >= pageViewTop) 
                && (elemTop <= pageViewBottom)
                && (elemBottom <= pageViewBottom) 
                && (elemTop >= pageViewTop));               
        return isInView;
    }
});
```

`.testplace` is remaining "sticky" fixed to the bottom of the page until `.checkout-btn` comes in to view - the problem is that when `.checkout-btn` scrolls in to view `.testplace` is hidden BUT when `.checkout-btn` scrolls off the top of the page the `.testplace` div then comes back in to view. I only want `.testplace` to `.fadeIn` when `.checkout-btn` scrolls into viewport off the bottom of the page and NOT when it scrolls off the top of the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle for this?

Comment: Not really as this is an A/B test build, I can't post the entire HTML